# Couchdb installation issue

Tags: installation, couchdb, couchdb-2.0

After installing couchdb using [a script](https://gist.github.com/SinanGabel/eac83a2f9d0ac64e2c9d4bd936be9313#file-couchdb-2-0-install) I am having some issue, my couchdb instance in not running

Os is ubuntu 16.04
couchdb version 2.0.0

following is the error.

```
Feb 03 16:55:30 hisab-couchdb couchdb[2003]: [error] 2017-02-03T16:55:30.432974Z couchdb@localhost <0.250.0> -------- CRASH REPORT Process  (<0.250.0>) with 1 neighbors exited with reason: no match of right hand value {error,eacces} at couch_file:init/1(line:384) <= gen_server:init_it/6(line:328) <= proc_lib:init_p_do_apply/3(line:240) at gen_server:init_it/6(line:352) <= proc_lib:init_p_do_apply/3(line:240); initial_call: {couch_file,init,['Argument__1']}, ancestors: [<0.249.0>], messages: [], links: [#Port<0.4013>,<0.249.0>], dictionary: [], trap_exit: false, status: running, heap_size: 610, stack_size: 27, reductions: 508
Feb 03 16:55:30 hisab-couchdb couchdb[2003]: [info] 2017-02-03T16:55:30.439016Z couchdb@localhost <0.209.0> -------- db _users died with reason {{badmatch,{error,eacces}},[{couch_file,init,1,[{file,"src/couch_file.erl"},{line,384}]},{gen_server,init_it,6,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,328}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,240}]}]}
Feb 03 16:55:30 hisab-couchdb couchdb[2003]: [error] 2017-02-03T16:55:30.440295Z couchdb@localhost <0.251.0> -------- Could not open file ./data/_users.couch: permission denied
Feb 03 16:55:30 hisab-couchdb couchdb[2003]: [info] 2017-02-03T16:55:30.440380Z couchdb@localhost <0.209.0> -------- open_result error {error,eacces} for _users
Feb 03 16:55:30 hisab-couchdb couchdb[2003]: [error] 2017-02-03T16:55:30.440952Z couchdb@localhost <0.246.0> -------- CRASH REPORT Process  (<0.246.0>) with 1 neighbors exited with reason: no match of right hand value {error,eacces} at couch_auth_cache:ensure_users_db_exists/2(line:456) <= couch_auth_cache:open_auth_db/0(line:428) <= couch_auth_cache:reinit_cache/1(line:290) <= couch_auth_cache:init/1(line:166) <= gen_server:init_it/6(line:328) <= proc_lib:init_p_do_apply/3(line:240) at gen_server:init_it/6(line:352) <= proc_lib:init_p_do_apply/3(line:240); initial_call: {couch_auth_cache,init,['Argument__1']}, ancestors: [couch_secondary_services,couch_sup,<0.203.0>], messages: [], links: [<0.212.0>,<0.248.0>], dictionary: [], trap_exit: true, status: running, heap_size: 987, stack_size: 27, reductions: 376
Feb 03 16:55:30 hisab-couchdb couchdb[2003]: [error] 2017-02-03T16:55:30.443040Z couchdb@localhost <0.203.0> -------- Error starting Apache CouchDB:
Feb 03 16:55:30 hisab-couchdb couchdb[2003]:     {error,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,couch_secondary_services,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,auth_cache,{{badmatch,{error,eacces}},[{couch_auth_cache,ensure_users_db_exists,2,[{file,"src/couch_auth_cache.erl"},{line,456}]},{couch_auth_cache,open_auth_db,0,[{file,"src/couch_auth_cache.erl"},{line,428}]},{couch_auth_cache,reinit_cache,1,[{file,"src/couch_auth_cache.erl"},{line,290}]},{couch_auth_cache,init,1,[{file,"src/couch_auth_cache.erl"},{line,166}]},{gen_server,init_it,6,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,328}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,240}]}]}}}}}}
Feb 03 16:55:30 hisab-couchdb couchdb[2003]: [error] 2017-02-03T16:55:30.445063Z couchdb@localhost <0.212.0> -------- Supervisor couch_secondary_services had child auth_cache started with couch_auth_cache:start_link() at undefined exit with reason no match of right hand value {error,eacces} at couch_auth_cache:ensure_users_db_exists/2(line:456) <= couch_auth_cache:open_auth_db/0(line:428) <= couch_auth_cache:reinit_cache/1(line:290) <= couch_auth_cache:init/1(line:166) <= gen_server:init_it/6(line:328) <= proc_lib:init_p_do_apply/3(line:240) in context start_error
Feb 03 16:55:30 hisab-couchdb couchdb[2003]: [error] 2017-02-03T16:55:30.446328Z couchdb@localhost <0.204.0> -------- Supervisor couch_sup had child couch_secondary_services started with couch_secondary_sup:start_link() at undefined exit with reason {shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,auth_cache,{{badmatch,{error,eacces}},[{couch_auth_cache,ensure_users_db_exists,2,[{file,"src/couch_auth_cache.erl"},{line,456}]},{couch_auth_cache,open_auth_db,0,[{file,"src/couch_auth_cache.erl"},{line,428}]},{couch_auth_cache,reinit_cache,1,[{file,"src/couch_auth_cache.erl"},{line,290}]},{couch_auth_cache,init,1,[{file,"src/couch_auth_cache.erl"},{line,166}]},{gen_server,init_it,6,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,328}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"p..."},...]}]}}} in context start_error
Feb 03 16:55:30 hisab-couchdb couchdb[2003]: [error] 2017-02-03T16:55:30.446614Z couchdb@localhost <0.202.0> -------- CRASH REPORT Process  (<0.202.0>) with 0 neighbors exited with reason: {{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,couch_secondary_services,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,auth_cache,{{badmatch,{error,eacces}},[{couch_auth_cache,ensure_users_db_exists,2,[{file,"src/couch_auth_cache.erl"},{line,456}]},{couch_auth_cache,open_auth_db,0,[{file,"src/couch_auth_cache.erl"},{line,428}]},{couch_auth_cache,reinit_cache,1,[{file,"src/couch_auth_cache.erl"},{line,290}]},{couch_auth_cache,init,1,[{file,"src/couch_auth_cache.erl"},{line,166}]},{gen_server,init_it,6,[{file,"gen_ser..."},...]},...]}}}}},...} at application_master:init/4(line:134) <= proc_lib:init_p_do_apply/3(line:240); initial_call: {application_master,init,['Argument__1','Argument__2',...]}, ancestors: [<0.201.0>], messages: [{'EXIT',<0.203.0>,normal}], links: [<0.201.0>,<0.7.0>], dictionary: [], trap_exit: true, status: running, heap_size: 987, stack_size: 27, reductions: 152
Feb 03 16:55:30 hisab-couchdb couchdb[2003]: [info] 2017-02-03T16:55:30.446851Z couchdb@localhost <0.7.0> -------- Application couch exited with reason: {{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,couch_secondary_services,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,auth_cache,{{badmatch,{error,eacces}},[{couch_auth_cache,ensure_users_db_exists,2,[{file,"src/couch_auth_cache.erl"},{line,456}]},{couch_auth_cache,open_auth_db,0,[{file,"src/couch_auth_cache.erl"},{line,428}]},{couch_auth_cache,reinit_cache,1,[{file,"src/couch_auth_cache.erl"},{line,290}]},{couch_auth_cache,init,1,[{file,"src/couch_auth_cache.erl"},{line,166}]},{gen_server,init_it,6,[{file,"gen_ser..."},...]},...]}}}}},...}
Feb 03 16:55:30 hisab-couchdb couchdb[2003]: [os_mon] memory supervisor port (memsup): Erlang has closed
Feb 03 16:55:30 hisab-couchdb couchdb[2003]: [os_mon] cpu supervisor port (cpu_sup): Erlang has closed
```

Installation script I've used is https://gist.github.com/SinanGabel/eac83a2f9d0ac64e2c9d4bd936be9313#file-couchdb-2-0-install

Comment: Found the issue, couchdb was not starting because for user couchdb home directory is specified i.e. /home/couchdb which was not created.

I don't know how to remove that. so I've created a new home directory with premissions to couchdb user.

/opt/couchdb/bin/../erts-7.3/bin/beam.smp -K true -A 16 -Bd -- -root /opt/couchdb/bin/.. -progname couchdb -- -home /home/couchdb ...